# Can't center text when using colored

Tags: python

I am trying to center text in the terminal. I use:

```
import shutil
from termcolor import colored

columns = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
print("This is a "+colored("test",'white','on_red')+" run".center(columns))
```

However the text is not centered. It works if I remove the `colored` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did work to my end when I tried to pass color outside of print() function then pass it to as `fstring` method.

```
col = colored("test", 'white', 'on_red')
print(f"This is a {col} run".center(columns))
```